# Comparing a scanner input to elements in an array

Tags: java

I am new to java so forgive me if I am making a very simple mistake. I am attempting to make shop within a text based adventure game. I have created an array `shopItems` which stores a list of items as strings that the shop can sell. Here is a part of the method I use for the user to make purchases within the game.

```
String request = s.nextLine().toLowerCase();            
        for (int i = 0 ; i < shopItems.length ; i++)
        {
            if(request.equalsIgnoreCase(shopItems[i]))
            {
                System.out.println("We have this item in stock! That will be " + itemPrice[i] + " gold, "
                        + "would you like to purchase this item?");
                String command2 = s.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                if(command2.equals("yes") || command2.equals("y"))
                {
                    if (savings >= itemPrice[i])
                    {
                        System.out.println("Congratulations! You have purchased " + shopItems[i] + ". Thank you "
                                + "for your business.");
                        savings = savings - itemPrice[i];
                        inv.add(shopItems[i]);
                        magicShopPurchase();
                    }

                    else if (savings < itemPrice[i])
                    {
                        System.out.println("I'm sorry, you don't have enough gold to purchase this item! Try "
                                + "again when you have enough!");

                    }
                }
            }
            else if(request.equals("leave"))
            {
                System.out.println("Thank you! Please come again soon!");
                inMagicShop();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("I'm sorry, we don't have any of those in stock at the moment. Would you "
                        + "like to purchase a different item?");
                String command2 = s.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                if(command2.equals("yes") || command2.equals("y"))
                {
                    magicShopPurchase();
                }
                else if(command2.equals("no") || command2.equals("n"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Thank you! Please come again soon!");
                    inMagicShop();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Haha, you kiss your mother with that mouth? Come back some other time!");
                    inMagicShop();
                }
            }
        }
```

I am trying to compare the scanner input with `shopItems` to check if the item that the user wants to purchase is available in the shop, however it does not recognize any of the elements in `shopItems`. Am I doing something wrong with this method/is there a mistake somewhere? This is my first post here so please forgive me if I have left out anything important.

EDIT

First is where I call the method to store elements into `shopItems`.

```
try {
    itemList = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\gravy_000\\Desktop\\Software Development 1\\GameProject\\src\\hallSim\\magicitems.txt")));
    read(itemList);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Second is the method I used to read the text file and store it into `shopItems`.

```
public static void read(String shopList) {
    shopItems = shopList.split("\\r?\\n");
}
```

Here is a link to the text file in Dropbox
`https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbfsr1fj2yzus1q/magicitems.txt?dl=0`

Comment: is `shopItems` a `String[]`, or another type of array? Your code suggests so.

Comment: Yes `shopItems` is a `String[]`

Comment: Your code logic looks fine, can you give an example where it's not executing as expected? Are you sure that there aren't extra spaces or things like that?

Comment: Yes, for example, `shopItems[11] = "Rags"`. I have tried all different variations of `Rags` as the input `request`, such as `Rags` `rags` and also with adding a space after those two just in case one was accidentally added. Would it help to know that the elements in `shopItems` were taken from a text file? Each line of the file is a separate element. I have had no errors in regards to `shopItems` in my code except for this problem I'm having, so I couldn't imagine that it would have to do with that.

Comment: Could you please show the code where you load the data for `shopItems`, as well as a sample for what the source file looks like?

Comment: Didn't see that you asked for the source file, I included the code that you asked for and a Dropbox link for the text file that I am using. Sorry about that!

Comment: I ran your code with your file, I entered `"rags"` and it worked fine.. so what's the issue?

Comment: Now that you say that I realize I should have added more of my code. I didn't think it would be important but I have an `If/Else` statement and an `Else` statement to go along with the `if(request.equalsIgnoreCase(shopItems[i]))`. Would you like me to add that?

Comment: sure, it could be the problem

Comment: I added it to the first chunk of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are telling the user that the item is not found, the *first* time `request.equalsIgnoreCase(shopItems[i])` returns false, NOT when `request` is not present.

So you should replace the code by something like this or equivalent:

```
    String request = s.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    if(request.equals("leave")) {
        //leave
    } else {
        boolean isItemInStock = false;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < shopItems.length ; i++) {
            if(request.equalsIgnoreCase(shopItems[i])) {
                isItemInStock = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(isItemInStock) {
            System.out.println("We have this item in stock! That will be " + itemPrice[i] + " gold, "
                    + "would you like to purchase this item?");
            //...
        } else {
            System.out.println("I'm sorry, we don't have any of those in stock at the moment. Would you "
                    + "like to purchase a different item?");
            //...
        }
    }
```

Note how the if/else statement that handles what to with `request` is *outside* the main loop.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped me to get my code working!